# efficient check if datagridview has been modified

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i need to efficiently check if datagridview has been modified so i will save the edit to the database, the problem is that i can't find an efficient way to do it, unsafe options are welcome aswell, thanks in advance

p.s. it doesn't matter what the change is, what matter to me the most is to know if it has been changed not to waste processing power saving the same data to the db (yeah kinda trying to state the obvious so the automatic check for the question length would let me pass and post the question)

Comment: use [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and in you want to know when user changed the value you could use [DataGridView.CellEndEdit Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView.CellValueChanged event is just made for this purpose, just make sure  you don't include row index of -1

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RowIndex > -1)
        changed = true;
    }
```

Comment: But this will be triggered every time you change cell value. Even if 100 cell you modify it be fired. Might not be the most efficient